# How can a c++ program compiled with -m32 flag do 64-bit system calls?

Tags: c++, compilation, openmp, 32-bit

I have been compiling c++ binaries from a benchmark suite using the -m32 bit flag. I intended to run these in a computer system simulator which only supports 32-bit ELFs. However this binary is doing a system call that is not supported named getdents64 which is a 64-bit system call. I thought this was not possible due to the -m32 flag. What am I misunderstanding here? The code itself does use openmp calls and is compiled with the -fopenmp flag. Is openmp the culprit here or something else?

Comment: `getdents64` was added in Linux 2.4, deep in the 32-bit era. What leads you to believe that it is not supported?

Comment: Hi @dratenik The simulator shoots of an error message whenever a system call is unsupported. It supposedly only supports "the most ccommon linux system calls". The simulator is Multi2Sim (https://github.com/Multi2Sim/multi2sim) and the ISA i chose to simulate was x86

Comment: Ok, that is not an issue of 32 vs. 64 bits, that is an issue of simulator omitted this syscall. The syscall itself is available in 32bit mode.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. I thought the 64 in its named reffered to 64-bits, guess thats something else. Thank you very much @dratenik